# Interation of all pages in Pages Library

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, wss

My colleagues and I were looking into a excessive SPRequests in SharePoint MOSS 2007. We saw that the probable cause would be that when a link is clicked, **ALL** pages in the page library is being called (this is based on reviewing the SQL profiler). There will be multiple SQL calls which implies that there is something iterating through all the pages in the SPWeb's page library. We checked all of our custom code and also the ULS logs and we don't think it is our code.

Could this behavior be configured or perhaps there is more to this than we thing?

Hope to knows whats up with this as this issue is maddening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excessive SPRequest warning might not be necessarily because of bad custom code although it is one of the causes. It can also be caused if you have large number of pages and sites, because PortalSiteMapProvider iterates through all pages and site nodes.

http://insomniacgeek.com/how-to-debug-potentially-excessive-number-of-sprequest-objects-error-message/